# How to get the local path of a file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Since in wordpress, the files/images uploaded are stored in 3 different sizes thus taking up the memory. I have a code that re sizes the image given the URL of that image. The code to resize is:

```
$img = wp_get_image_editor( $image_url );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $img ) ) {
    $img->resize( 200, 200, false );
    $filename = $img->generate_filename(
        'final', 
        ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads',
        NULL 
    );
    $img->save($filename);
}
```

So I want to use this code to resize the image from the local path of the user so that I don't use up too much of my memory. 
Can anyone tell me how to get the local path and url of the file uploaded by url?

Answer (score 8):

How about this for getting the local path of an image from its URL? :

```
function ContentUrlToLocalPath($url){
    preg_match('/.*(\/wp\-content\/uploads\/\d+\/\d+\/.*)/', $url, $mat);
    if(count($mat) > 0) return ABSPATH . $mat[1];
    return '';
}
```

It assumes the file is located in the uploads folder.

Comment: very nice answer !!

Comment: All good, but it assumes to much for my taste. Not just the uploads folder but also the structure of the uploads subfolders to be in a numbers format.

Answer (score 6):

we could use `get_attached_file()` for retrieve attached file path based on attachment ID

try:

```
<?php 
get_attached_file( $attachment_id); 
?>
```

Comment: what i want to do is instead of using the image inside the uploads folder, i want to use the url of the image that is in a user's personal computer(when he uploads the image), and use that url to resize the image and save it in my folder. Thank you for your response.