# How can I print the size of uploaded files in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am uploading files with ZIP extension to Wordpress media library. How can I print the size of these files in KB?
I just want people to see how many KB the file to download is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions is incomplete, could you please tell us how are you planning on displaying the files to the users to download, if you are directly copy-pasting your link (which I am assuming).

One workaround could be to create a shortcode to calculate the filesize:

First we need to get local directory for the file on the URL (since normal PHP functions do not support files on a remote server) and in order to check size of a file outside of the local server you will need to have cURL enabled on your server.

**THIS WILL NOT WORK ON FILES OUTSIDE OF THE LOCAL SERVER (i.e. outside of the domain)**

You need to place both the snippets in your *functions.php* file in your theme editor.

To find the local directory from URL, we can use this function from [@NoOne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33317639/9041904)

```
function ContentUrlToLocalPath($url) {
preg_match('/.*(\/wp\-content\/uploads\/\d+\/\d+\/.*)/', $url, $mat);
if(count($mat) > 0) return ABSPATH . $mat[1];
return ''; 
}
```

Next we will create our shortcode to get our filesize:

```
function fileSize_shortcode($attr){
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
     
            'url' => '#',
 
        ), $attr );
 
    $url = $args['url'];
    if(file_exists(ContentUrlToLocalPath($url))) {
        echo filesize(ContentUrlToLocalPath($url)) >> 10 . ' KB';
    }
    else {
        echo '';
    }
}
 
add_shortcode( 'filesize' , 'fileSize_shortcode' );
```

Now you can use the shortcode `[filesize url="https://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/school-boy-holding-books-apple-1.jpg"]` which will return the filesize as `616 KB`.

[image: Shortcode]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking the question incompletely. Your answer worked! thank you for your help